CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty() sets unit to px when not specified
I have an Angular app that uses the HTMLElement style property to set CSS variables.
---COMPONENT---

export class WallArtComponent {
   private _style!: CSSStyleDeclaration;

   constructor(
       private readonly host: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
   ) {
       this._style = this.host.nativeElement.style;
   }

   @Input()
   public get width(): number {
       const width = this._style.getPropertyValue("--width");
       return width === "" ? 0 : parseInt(width);
   }
   public set width(value: number) {
       this._style.setProperty("--width", value.toString());
   }
}

--- PARENT HTML ---

<wall-art [width]="16"></wall-art>

Thus, as Angular sets the value of width, the corresponding element style is set to: style="--width: 16;". And the corresponding styles that reference the var(--width) variable update accordingly. So, it works!
However, every once in a while, the value of var(--width) is set with a px unit instead of a unitless integer. Meaning, instead of getting something like: --width: 16;, I'll get: --width: 16px;.
Does anyone know why? Could this be an Angular lifecycle issue?

becaue the width as an HTML attribute is a legacy attribute coming from older HTML versions. It can only use values in pixels. The pixels themselves are not typed in as it would be unnecessarily redundant. The readout with JS is correct though.

Are you suggesting that there is a property collision between the native width property and the one I added? I didn't think of that

This approach should help maintain the consistency of your CSS variable and avoid the occasional px unit being appended to your --width variable.
    export class WallArtComponent {
   private _style!: CSSStyleDeclaration;

   constructor(
       private readonly host: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
   ) {
       this._style = this.host.nativeElement.style;
   }

   @Input()
   public get width(): number {
       const width = this._style.getPropertyValue("--width");
       return width === "" ? 0 : parseInt(width);
   }
   public set width(value: number) {
        const numericValue = typeof value === 'string' ? parseInt(value) : value;
       this._style.setProperty("--width", numericValue.toString());
   }
}

